# Sequence of setStates are not working inside api call, why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set two states after retrieve some data from api call.

```
const [value1, setValue1] = useState();
const [value2, setValue2] = useState();

const getValues = async () => {
await valuesService
  .getValuesFromBackEnd(params)
  .then(data => {
    setValue1(data.value1);
    setValue2(data.value2);
  });
};
```

Using the code above it only works with setValue1. If change the setStates order it only works for setValue2. If I add a useDispatch before both of them, they work perfectly, setting both states. Also work fine if I put one of them inside a setTimeOut function. Someone can explain why this happen? Examples of code working as intended:

```
const [value1, setValue1] = useState();
const [value2, setValue2] = useState();

const getValues = async () => {
await valuesService
  .getValuesFromBackEnd(params)
  .then(data => {
    setValue1(data.value1);
    setTimeout(() => {
       setValue2(data.value2);
    }, 3000);
  });
};
```

or

```
const [value1, setValue1] = useState();
const [value2, setValue2] = useState();
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const getValues = async () => {
await valuesService
  .getValuesFromBackEnd(params)
  .then(data => {
    dispatch (something);
    setValue1(data.value1);
    setValue2(data.value2);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have instances where you are setting multiple bits of state simultaneously, it is best the use `useReducer` instead of `setState`. Kent Dodds has a great [article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/should-i-usestate-or-usereducer) on the differences.

Ultimately, it isn't that value1 and value2 aren't both being set, it's that, when using `useState` 'set' methods, they aren't truly being updated at the same time. Your value1 is updated first, which fires rerenders, then value2 is updated, firing another round of rerenders. When you use `useReducer`, you can update both together.